# Do we have the capacity to bless Hashem?

Tags: blessing, theology

When children are taught that Baruch Ata Ado... means " the source of all blessings' ' as opposed to "blessed are you Hashem' ' because we don't have the capacity to bless our creator.

Is that accurate? (I've heard that Rav Chaim volozion agreed with this aforementioned statement. I couldn't find sources for this though.) Is this true BTW? Sources pls….

The issue I have is that every one of us "Blesses Hashem '' when we consume food. Additionally we see It's existed since time immemorial. Avraham's servant, Naomi's friends, and Yisro were all  comfortable with this phrase.

Also we say קדוש אתה ונורא שמך.
What about when we say ברוך שם כבוד?

The Gemora in Berakhos 7a:4 explicitly says that Hashem asked Rebbi Yisrael to Bless him???!!!!

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.24.27
https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ruth.4.14
https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.18.10

So, how do we reconcile this supposed Rav Chaim and our elementary school teachers?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Nefesh_HaChayim,_Gate_II_2.1

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/130303/jewish/G-ds-Nourishment.htm

Comment: https://www.torahmusings.com/2018/10/the-meaning-of-blessing-hashem/

Comment: The reason behind translating it as "source" is because it can be seen to stem from "breicha" a pool/source of water. Also a common refrain is "Boruch Hashem" when asked how we are / how something went....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is that indeed, we can and do literally bless Hashem. Based on the Rashbah in his Chidushei Aggadot on Berachot 7a, he makes a case that *beracha* is not associated with praise and thanks, but with increase and abundance (e.g. Shemot 23:25, Tehillim 119:12), and by saying a *beracha*, we are causing Hashem to increase his mercy on His creations.

This is a Kabbalistic answer, and the Nefesh Hachaim quotes him, the Zohar and Berachot 7a, in explaining that yes, we bless Hashem, and this draws a flow of life from Him.

---

<sup>Philosophically, we cannot give any "thing" to Hashem. In actuality, Hashem has made it possible for there to be a give and take between us and the Shechina, and we partner with Him (forge a relationship with Him) in building and blessing the world, and making it holy. There are indeed even deeper avenues to explore in how much we mean to Hashem, and how meaningful a heartfelt *bracha* is from a *pashute Yid* is to Him (infinitely). To fully justify that would take this question way beyond scope as essays would need to be written about esoteric and controversial issues (a good start might be [Derech Mitzvotecha](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3101998/jewish/Lessons-in-Derech-Mitzvosecha.htm)). I might try to bring a few more sources and explanations if I find any that would fit well here, but for now I will rely on your intuitive understanding of love and relationships, as is explained in Chassidus.</sup>

Comment: Chiddushei Aggados is by the Maharsha? There's a Chidushei HaRashba al Aggados HaShas?

Comment: @Dov yes although it didn't get widely circulated https://seforimcenter.com/Chidushei-HaRashba-al-Aggadot-HaShas__p-2252.aspx

Comment: Correct so you should label the sefer correctly, as at the moment it reads like the Rashba authored Chiddushei Aggados which is incorrect.

Comment: @Dov there are so many references to it as simply "Chiddushei Agadot", that I don't think it warrants a change. Would you give me an upvote if I did? :P

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I will bring the opinions against the position that we can bless Hashem. If nobody beats me to it, another day I will bring the opinions in favour (Rashbah, Nefesh Hachaim, Kabbalah), which is what I teach. It should be noted that the explanation brought here goes on the "plain meaning", as explanied by many Rishonim.

There is a dispute among the rishonim about what בָּרוּךְ/*Baruch*/"Blessed" in
בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ("Blessed are You") means.

- Avudraham [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham%2C_Weekday_Prayers%2C_Blessings_on_Torah.1?vhe=Abudarham._Lisbon,_1489.&lang=en&sbsq=%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%97%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%9D&with=SidebarSearch&lang2=en) that the conjugation of the word is similar to רַחוּם/*Rachum*/Merciful One, and therefore it means "The Source of Blessing".
- [Sefer HaChinuch Mitzva 430](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.430.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that when we say בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה, we are not blessing God, Who is the Master of all blessing and abundance. It is an admission that all we desire comes from Him and His goodness, and by admitting so we pray that our heart and the hearts of others are correctly aligned with this truth, and come to praise Him.
- [Ibn Ezra on Shemot 18:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.18.10?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en),  [Rabbeinu Bachaye ben Asher, Kad Hakemach, Bracha](https://www.sefaria.org/Kad_HaKemach%2C_Blessing.1?lang=bi), [R' Yom Tov Lipman in Sefer Hanitzachon ch. 131](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52625&st=&pgnum=106), [R' Yosef Albo in Sefer Ha'Ikkarim 2:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_2.26.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) all concur.
- It can be used an expression of general praise or thanks. [Rashi on Ezra 7:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.7.27?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he) could be explained that way.
- [Radak's](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaShorashim%2C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9A.1?lang=he&with=Navigation&lang2=he) and [R' Yona's](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36864&st=&pgnum=120) Sifrei Shorashim both define it as praise and thanks.
- See also [Chizkuni on Bereshit 24:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.27?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=he)
- See also [Midrash Otiyot D'Rabbi Akiva](https://hebrewbooks.org/43003), who says Hashem started the Torah with the letter Bet, because the Bet argued "with me people will praise you every day, as it says *Baruch*..."

Comment: There is a discussion of this point, with all of the above mentioned, in the appendix of Pathway to Prayer